# The effect of wither

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Olivia Voldaren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOlivia%20Voldaren%5d) is enchanted with [Fists of the Demigod](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFists%20of%20the%20Demigod%5d) and you activate the ability to deal damage to a target creature, does this damage come in the form of -1/-1 counters? If it does, and the target is a [Spirit en-Kor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpirit%20en-Kor%5d), can the Spirit en-Kor redirect the -1/-1 counter?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Wither applies to all damage, not only combat damage.

> 702.79a Wither is a static ability. Damage dealt to a creature by a source with wither isn’t marked on that creature. Rather, it causes that source’s controller to put that many -1/-1 counters on that creature. See rule 119.3.

Yes, Spirit en-Kor can still use its ability to redirect the damage. Olivia Voldaren is still dealing damage, it's just that the effects of that damage are different than normal, so the Spirit's ability can be used. And when the damage is redirected, the source of the damage is still Olivia, so Wither still applies.

Comment: I cannot find any rule to back up my last sentence, though it is implied by the last ruling on Spirit en-Kor. Anyone know a CR that makes it clear that redirecting damage does not change the source (or type)?

Comment: Redirection of damage is a type of replacement effect so I imagine it would be handled similarly to multiple replacement effects on one event.

Comment: RE: CR rules 614.9. defines redireciton and replacement effects in general are outlined in 614 but it is pretty long

Comment: Re "*Wither applies to all damage*", See [Puncture Blast](https://scryfall.com/card/eve/60/puncture-blast)

Comment: Re "*I cannot find any rule to back up my last sentence*", The source of the damage is defined by the effect ("Olivia Voldaren deals"), not by the rules. And nothing about Spirit en-Kor's redirection effect replaces the source.

Comment: @ikegami It is not clear to me from the rules alone that the effect dealing the damage is not the redirection effect.

Comment: The rules are clear: You follow the instructions of the ability, which is to change the creature to which the damage is dealt. Period. Replacement effects only replace what they say they replace. You won't find any rules that says they replacement effects don't changes things they don't say they change. The event being replaced is "Olivia Voldaren deals 1 damage to Spirit en-Kor", and Spirit en-Kor changes to what the damage is dealt, so the replaced event is "Olivia Voldaren deals 1 damage to <some other creature>". There's absolutely no mention of changing the source in Spirit en-Kor.

Comment: As the name suggests, redirection simply redirects the damage. It doesn't prevent the damage then cause the redirector to deal damage.

Comment: "The next 1 damage that would be dealt to Spirit en-Kor this turn is dealt to target creature you control instead." It seems pretty clear to me that it's the same damage, with the same source and the same wither modification. The spirit just changes where the damage hits.